# Creating a Subset from a Dataframe using a Group Based on summary values

Tags: r, dplyr, sample

`count(df1,age,gender)`

```
age   gender  n
25    M       4
32    F       3
```

`full_df`

```
patient_ID   age   gender
pt1          23    M
pt2          26    F
...
```

I would like to create a 4:1 age/sex matched subset of full_df based on count stats of df1. For example, I have 4 male patients aged 25 in df1, so I would like to pull 16 random patients from full_df. And 12 32yo females.

I need to find a way to shuffle `full_df`, then add 1:len(group) to it as follows:

```
patient_ID  age  gender  order
pt100       25   M       1
pt251       25   M       2
pt201       25   M       3
...
pt376       26   M       1
pt872       26   M       2
pt563       26   M       3
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a small example for you based only on age (since there was no example df available this saves a lot of typing) but you can easily add gender to the method.
First we join the dataframe with the count information to the full dataframe, and then sample the number of rows per age group (in this example 2 times n, you would want to do 4 times n but my df is too small).
Then we add a new column 'order' with numbers ranging from 1 to the number of samples and lastly drop the 'n' column.

```
df1 = data.frame(age = c(25,32),
                 n = c(1,2))


df = data.frame(patient_ID  = 1:10,
               age = c(rep(25,4),rep(32,6)))

df %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = 'age') %>% 
  group_by(age) %>% 
  sample_n(n*2) %>% 
  mutate(order = 1:n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-n)
```

this gives the output with the selected patients (in line with the numbers in df1):

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  patient_ID   age order
       <int> <dbl> <int>
1          4    25     1
2          2    25     2
3         10    32     1
4          9    32     2
5          7    32     3
6          8    32     4
```